# Creating a Dib by only specifying the size with GDI+ and DotNet

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I have just recently discovered the difference between different constructors in GDI+.  Going:

`var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);`

creates a DDB (Device Dependent Bitmap) whereas:

`var bmp = new Bitmap(someFile);`

creates a DIB (Device Independent Bitmap).  This is really not usually important, except when handling very large images (where a DDB will run out of memory, and run out of memory at different sizes depending on the machine and its video memory).  I need to create a DIB rather than DDB, but specify the height, width and pixelformat.  Does anyone know how to do this in DotNet.  Also is there a guide to what type of Bitmap (DIB or DDB) is being created by which Bitmap constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the best way to do this is to allocate the memory yourself, and then then create the bitmap with:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, format, scan0)
```

This way you can create huge bitmaps without having an out of memory error.

Comment: how to create a smaller bitmap from Dib? May you help to check this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152072/create-bitmapsource-of-fixed-size-from-dibintptr